# SQL Server 2008 Install / Data Location

Tags: migration, sql-server

Am about to try and install SQL Server 2008 R2 for the second time. How and when during an install can I configure my data to be held on the D:/ drive as opposed to the default C:/ drive?

Comment: should probably move this over to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Indeed good sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143219.aspx

Step 15:

Instance root directory — By default, the instance root directory is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110. To specify a non-default root directory, use the field provided, or click Browse to locate an installation folder.

Comment: No problem. You have to configure the instance instead of accepting the default. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

To get the full control to it when you come to the "Database Engine Configuration" step:
[image]
Click the tab Data Directories:

[image]